# How to set border color for EditText for validation error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am applying validation on my login form in android application.

If any `EditText` fields is `null` (empty) then I want to set Red color border for that `EditText`.

If user fill any data in this Red bordered `EditText` then it should turn to default EditText.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 23):

Just a tip:

Why don't you use `EditText.setError("Oh, this is wrong");`

[Relevant](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setError%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) documentation says:

> Sets the right-hand compound drawable of the TextView to the "error"
>   icon and sets an error message that will be displayed in a popup when
>   the TextView has focus. The icon and error message will be reset to
>   null when any key events cause changes to the TextView's text. If the
>   error is null, the error message and icon will be cleared.

[Another blog entry covering this topic.](http://blog.donnfelker.com/2011/11/23/android-validation-with-edittext/)

Comment: +1.  Perfect answer for me.  Straightforward, simple, and stock Android code.